# I need a library to load images

Tags: c++, image, api, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++ Image Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284498/c-c-image-loading)

I need a C\C++ cross-platform library for loading/displaying images(jpg,gif,png,tga). I will use this library to display images in WinAPi/OpenGL.

Comment: Lots of answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284498/c-c-image-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at such libraries as [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/), [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) and [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/). Take your pick. There are plenty more.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one (and best, IMO) is [stb_image](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c). This is a single C source file that has decoders for JPG, PNG, TGA, BMP and PSD! Read the comments at the top of the file if you want to generate a header file for it.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick(more extensions), OpenCV
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/