# How can I create texture in DirectX 9 without d3dx9?

Tags: directx, windows-store-apps

Windows 8 Store don't want to see `d3dx9` in my app, that was written in `DirectX 9`. But I need `D3DXCreateTexture` function. I was found `DirectXTex`, but it wants `DirectX 11`. Is there any way to avoid rewriting all in `DirectX 11`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must load raw bitmap data. There are many ways:

- write your own loader ( not in 21st century oO )
- use library for a formats you need. Such as libpng, libjpeg, more on Google =)
- use multiformat library ([C/C++ Image Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284498/c-c-image-loading)). FreeImage is my favorite.

Then you must create [IDirect3DTexture9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via [D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemoryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you are ready to go =)

**Update:**

Okay. We can't use it `D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemory`. So... we can implement it.
As earlier, we must load bitmap to memory somehow (I prefer use FreeImage). Then we create *empty* [IDirect3DTexture9*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via **[CreateTexture()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** method. Then we copy contents of bitmap to that texture using [LockRect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[UnlockRect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That time we ready to go surely, because I've tested it! =) Test VS2012 solution including FreeType : [link](http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/pN70/fb6Ogl9iiFN12rI8g) (messy and dirty, rewrite it please and wrap in a class )
The core function:

```
void CreateTexture(const wchar_t* filename)
{
unsigned int width(0), height(0);
std::vector<unsigned char> bitmap;
LoadBitmapFile(filename, bitmap, width, height); // Wrapped FreeImage

// Create empty IDirect3DTexture9*
pDevice->CreateTexture(width, height, 1, 0, 
                           D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &pTexture, 0);
if (!pTexture)
{
    throw std::runtime_error( "CreateTexture failed");
}

D3DLOCKED_RECT rect;
pTexture->LockRect( 0, &rect, 0, D3DLOCK_DISCARD );
unsigned char* dest = static_cast<unsigned char*>(rect.pBits);
memcpy(dest, &bitmap[0], sizeof(unsigned char) * width * height * 4);
pTexture->UnlockRect(0);
```

}

Hope it helps.

P.S. Actually there was another problem: projection matrix. You will need to create it manually or use some math lib, because D3DXMatrix..() functions you can't use.

Comment: D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemory is in `d3dx9.lib`, i can't use it

Comment: I've updated my answer: we can create texture resources without D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemory.

Comment: if it work's thats it) for matrix - DirectXMath using (#ifdef Win8). but will it be accepted by windows app store? i don't know after reading this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wingameswithdirectx/thread/c082b208-0d95-4c41-852f-9450340093f4/

Answer (score -1):

It seems the `DirectX 9` code must be rewriten with `DirectX 11`, cause `DirectXTK`, `DirectXTex`, `DirectXMath` libs works only with DX11. More information I have found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wingameswithdirectx/thread/c082b208-0d95-4c41-852f-9450340093f4/