# How to open an image weather is it a TIFF,JPG and PNG and how to display it in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to display an image using an MFC application. I am struggling to create image control. I was used Activex image 2.0 for opening an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That's not the type of question for which you can expect a good answer here. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: **"How to open an image whether is it a TIFF,JPG and PNG"** I suggest you could refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168797/opening-and-displaying-an-image-in-c)
**"how to display it in Visual C++?"** I suggest you could try [rendering GIF, JPEG, Icon, or Bitmap Files with OleLoadPicture](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739/Rendering-GIF-JPEG-Icon-or-Bitmap-Files-with-OleLo)